# Paged virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I am currently studing exam questions but stuck on this one, I hope someone can help me out to understand.

**Question**: Assume that we have a paged virtual memory with a page size of 4Ki byte.
Assume that each process has four segments (for example: code, data, stack,
extra) and that these can be of arbitrary but given size. How much will the
operating system loose in internal fragmentation?

**The answer is**: Each segment will in average give rise to 2Ki byte of fragmentation.
This will in average mean 8 Ki byte per process.
If we for example have 100 processes this is a total loss of 800 Ki byte.

**My question**:

1. How the answer get the 2Ki byte of fragmentation for each segement, how is that possible we can calculate the size, am I missing something here?
2. If we have 8Ki byte per process, that would not even fit in a 4Ki byte page isn't that actually a external fragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

This is academic BS designed to make things confusing.

They are saying probability wise, the last page in the sections in the executable file will only use 1/2 the page size on average. You can't count that size, they are just doing simple combinatorics.  That presumes behavior of the linker.

Comment: OK, just assume they doing some presumes behavior of the size, but how does 8Ki byte process and 4Ki byte page result in a internal fragmentation (my 2nd question) ?

Comment: They are assuming that each section of the executable does not take up an entire page and that the on average each section wastes 1/2 a page.